# Пример аргумента функции по шаблону

Tags: python

Функция, делающая скриншоты экрана:

```
autopy.bitmap.capture_screen(rect: Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]])
```

Там где float - это координаты экрана. Еще три раза Tuple, я не понимаю как это записать. Я хочу сделать скрины небольших участок экрана ((500,300),(550,350))

Comment: а если `((float, float), (float, float))`  - попробуйте в консоли `type((1,))`

Comment: когда посылаете нужный вид аргумента функция работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]]` - это аннотация типа (см. [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) с использованием псевдонимов типов ([Type aliases](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-aliases)). Псевдоним `Tuple` соответствует типу `tuple`. То что внутри квадратных скобок - предполагаемое содержимое кортежа (tuple).

Таком "шаблону" типа соответствует аргумент вида `((500.0, 300.0), (550.0, 350.0))` (целые числа тоже подойдут).

Аннотация типа сама по себе не влияет на работу функции, тип интерпретатором не проверяется.